# FLOT: draw bar not starting from axis

Tags: flot

I am trying to draw some bars which are not starting from axis, i mean, e.g., for the dataset [[1,2], [1,5]], what I want to have is a bar between these two points, not [[1,0], [1,5]], which starts from XAxis.

is there any plug-in which can support this?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For a series of data with bars you can specify a 3rd point which is the bottom of the bar.  See the [API.txt](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) for details:

> Lines and points take two coordinates.
>   For filled lines and bars, you can
>   specify a third coordinate which is
>   the bottom of the filled area/bar
>   (defaults to 0).

Here's an example that is close to what you want:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [{
    data: [[1,5,2]], //x=1, bottom of bar is 2, top of bar is 5
    bars: { show: true, align:'center', barWidth:0.3 }
},
{ //your line series data and options here }
],
options);
```